# How do I rearrange my linear layout with weights?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I am currently using a linear layout structure that looks as follows:
[image]

The associated xml code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLoadMoreScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/altercolor2"
    android:layout_gravity="top">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/columnOne"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight=".53"
             android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
               android:id="@+id/first_header"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               layout="@layout/item_header" />

           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/first_container"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight=".47"
          android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                 android:id="@+id/second_header"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 layout="@layout/item_header" />

            <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/second_container"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:gravity="top" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/third_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/item_header" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/third_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLoadMoreScrollView>
```

However, I would like to rearrange that so that it looks like:
[image]

Is there a way I can rearrange the same with linearlayout? or do I have to use some other form of layout like relativelayout. I am pretty confused about the same. Also, would like to include the headers with the containers(the include code), is there a way I can easily achieve this?

Thanks!

After altering a code a bit, i had a little success moving the second header and second layout on top, but the first header is next to first layout instead on top, and same for third.Is there a way to fix it? I have attached the image here:
[image]

and the code is as follows:

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLoadMoreScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/altercolor2"
    android:layout_gravity="top">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:baselineAligned="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/columnOne"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
               android:id="@+id/second_header"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               layout="@layout/item_header" />

           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/second_container"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:baselineAligned="true">

            <include
                 android:id="@+id/first_header"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="0.50"
                 layout="@layout/item_dashboard_header" />

            <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/first_container"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="0.50"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/third_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                layout="@layout/item_dashboard_header" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/third_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLoadMoreScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you close to what you want. Use the same amount of `weight` for the two `View`s to take up equal amounts of space. This is obviously pseudocode for the `layout` because it seems you know the properties.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ...>
    <SecondView
        width="match_parent"
        height="wrap_content"
        .../>
    <LinearLayout
       width="match_parent"
       height="wrap_content"
       ...>
      <LinearLayout
          width="0dp"
          height="wrap_content"
          layout_weight="1"
          orientation="vertical">
       <include
             android:id="@+id/first_header"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="0.50"
             layout="@layout/item_dashboard_header" />

        <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/first_container"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="0.50"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           />
     </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
          width="0dp"
          height="wrap_content"
          layout_weight="1"
          orientation="vertical">
       <include
            android:id="@+id/third_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            layout="@layout/item_dashboard_header" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/third_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
      </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When you use `weight` in a horizontal `LinearLayout` your `width` should be "0dp" and in a vertical `LinearLayout` your `height` should be "0dp".

Now wrap these

```
<include
             android:id="@+id/first_header"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="0.50"
             layout="@layout/item_dashboard_header" />

        <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/first_container"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="0.50"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           />
```

in a vertical `LinearLayout` as I have above with `ThirdView` and `FirstView`. In whatever order you need them.

Comment: It's not possible to set it that way as it's showing only the first container when I do it this way,Can you illustrate with respect to my code for the required layout, so second is on top, first and third alongside as i nthe picture, also not sure if I have to replace those linearlayouts within the linearlayouts somehow, I added linearlayouts instead of any kid of views within the parent linearlayouts as in the code

Comment: I guess I don't understand. See my edit. Maybe that's what you mean. I didn't pay attention to where each number was when I first wrote the code

Comment: I am kind of confused with the linear layouts contained within the other linear layouts instead of views that you have illustrated in the code.Also, setting width or height to 0dp makes that particular layout invisible in my case. Is, there a way you can use my code(with exact layouts and included headers as shown) and explain your answer for the same ?

Comment: That makes two of us because I'm confused on what you are confused about. The `View`s that I have used would be your `<include>` layouts. So you would need to change the `width` and `height` as I have them. You shouldn't need that many nested `LinearLayout`s like you have

Comment: I just plan to get rid of weights from the first linearlayout and adjust them between second and third somehow, however, the top /first linearlayout takes over when i do as per your code and the second/third view disappear leaving a huge blank below the first.Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you make sure to have `android:orientation="vertical"` for the root `LinearLayout`? Either you didn't do that or you have height set to `match_parent` for whatever layout is taking over would be my guess

Comment: I have added my code alongside to compare(edited your code ,and placed mine below yours). However if I set the orientation to horizontal, the second header and container show on top as expected.However, the first and the third headers show alongside in the form, first header|first container|third header|third container. I wanted to place the headers on top of the respective containers, but these are showing adjacent to these, is there any way I can fix that?

Comment: Your child `LinearLayout` shouldn't have a vertical `orientation`

Comment: even if i make it horizontal, it shows the headers next to the containers which isn't what i was expecting

Comment: I have edited. See if that helps.Wrap each header and content in a vertical `LinearLayout` inside of the child horizontal `LinearLayout`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46710/discussion-between-justice-bauer-and-codemagic)

Comment: @JusticeBauer what problem are you having now?

Comment: Please check the edited question , the second header and container are fine where they are, just need to shift the first header on top of first container and same for third header and container and need to align both such that first header/container remain on left of third header/container as required and shown in image 2

Comment: Ok, your header and content go where I have `ThirdView` and `FirstView`, respectively. See my edit.

Comment: wrap as what? I tried making changes and they show one below the other instead of alongside. Can you alter your code by removing the first/thirsview ,which is confusing and add linearlayout and include statements to show what you are trying to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RelativeLayout` and it's really easy -

Just use `Android:Layout_AlignToRightOf="@id/LeftView"`
and `Android:Layout_AlignBelow="@id/TopView"` for the various views.

Ie: Your xmxl for your second pic should be:

```
     <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/Organize"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

             <LinearLayout   //or Whatever type of view you want
             android:id="@+id/Second"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                         <include.../>
             </LinearLayout>

                     <LinearLayout  //or Whatever type of view you want
                     android:id="@+id/First"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_below="@id/Second">
                             <include.../>
                     </LinearLayout>

                     <LinearLayout  //or Whatever type of view you want
                     android:id="@+id/Third"
                     androidlayout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_below="@id/Second"
                     android:layout_ToRightOf="@id/First>
                              <include.../>
                     </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

In your first pic, and your original MXML, you have created a `LinearLayout` and set it to `horizontal` (left to right) and then put a second `LinearLayout` after (to the right of) it.  Inside that second one, you have populated it with two items, that get distributed top to bottom. Using RelativeLayout is personal preference, but it makes controlling where you want things to appear on the screen a little more straightforward.

Comment: I don't have a textview. I have layouts within the main linear layout which makes it difficult to add relations like torightof etc, can you show with respect to my code?

Comment: one sec... RelativeView makes life easy.

Comment: the above code shows errors as android:layout_ToRightOf is not recognized in linear layouts

Comment: Should be `toRightOf` check the capitalization

Comment: +1 @codeMagic Yeah, I was writing from my mobile off the top of my head... Eclipse helps you when you type it, and SO is to help you solve problems, and gain understanding, not write perfect working code for you...

Comment: Using the above code makes the third layer invisible and places the first layer below the second one vertically, instead of first and third alongside (and below the first one vertically  as shown in the figure).Let me edit my code, found some success with codemagic's code ,but still struggling with header